# Free backup software

Tags: gratis, open-source, backup, ad-free

I need a free backup software with this requisites:

- Can run in background (like Steam)
- Must be able to do both manual and scheduled folder an files backup (this means you must be able to chose what folders and files to backup and which not)
- backup must be incremental
- 100% Free with no backup space managment limits and without ad
- Compatible with both Windows 10 and Linux Ubuntu

A good example is Fwbackup, but it can't run in background and is not compatible with Windows 10

Thanks!

Comment: What are you referring to with "GNU"? Does it have to be a GNU project? Or do you mean it has to be licensed under the GPL (instead of other free/open source licenses)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using duplicati on Windows for the past year and I really like it.  I have never tried it on Ubuntu, but they state Linux is supported on their website.

"Duplicati is free software and open source. You can use Duplicati for free even for commercial purposes. Source code is licensed under LGPL. Duplicati runs under Windows, Linux, MacOS. It requires .NET 4.5 or Mono."

It's biggest strength is the number of storage locations you can backup to.

"Duplicati works with standard protocols like FTP, SSH, WebDAV as well as popular services like Microsoft OneDrive, Amazon Cloud Drive & S3, Google Drive, box.com, Mega, hubiC and many others."

https://www.duplicati.com/

I would be interested to hear your experience running on Ubuntu.

Comment: It works perfectly on windows and on Ubuntu. Great answer!!